# What is this small, daisy-like wildflower found in open woods?

Tags: identification, wildflowers

I have this attractive little wildflower growing through my yard, and I would like the identification. They get from 6"-20" tall and very slender. Before blooming, the flower buds are curled downwards.It blooms from early April until summer. [image]

[image][image]

Comment: I would say it is an [oxeye daisy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leucanthemum_vulgare), if those petals were not so narrow…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [daisy fleabane, *Erigeron* sp.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erigeron). My best guess is [Robin's plantain, *E. pulchellus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erigeron_pulchellus), at least if you live in eastern North America. It's native there, and a very common "weed" of semi-disturbed areas, but it also is common in moist-ish open to moderately closed woods.